# Google Sign-In endpoint doesn't return the user's name anymore

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm using [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) on my iOS app. Everything was working well until recently when I noticed the app no longer gets the user's name, only the email address is returned.

I am getting a token through the app that I am sending to my server, which used to fetch the full information by sending a request to this endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=MYTOKEN
```

I'm getting this kind of answer now:

```
{

    "issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "issued_to": "o37l8g.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "audience": "o37l8g.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "user_id": "113504",
    "expires_in": ​814,
    "issued_at": ​1452991611,
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "email_verified": true

}
```

I tried to use other endpoints, like `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=` and `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=`, but none of them worked.

I also tried with the playground but cannot find which endpoint to use, my scope is well defined and I see in the iOS app that all the permissions are requested, but somehow it still doesn't return the user's name... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you verify that your account has a name set (what happens if you try with other accounts?). When you go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and request profile scope, then exchange the code for tokens, do you see a name when you add the id_token to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=

Comment: @StevenSoneff yes my account has a name set, and the problem is for all account. And no I don't see the name there either.

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to be an account problem. What version of the Google Sign-In SDK on iOS are you using? Can you add any snippet to the question showing how it is configured? Your link is to older G+ SDKs, have you tried using the latest one? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the access_token instead of the id_token, so you will be still able to query the tokeninfo endpoint to very your token using:
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=`

But now you can also query other endpoints to access to other informations, like the name:
`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=`

Check how you use the Google SignIn iOS SDK and make sure you are getting end sending to your server the access_token instead of the id_token.

example in Swift:

```
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
     let token = user.authentication.accessToken // YES
     let token = user.authentication.idToken // Maybe NO 
 ...
```

Comment: This worked for me. Weirdly the idToken works some of the time but not others which made it very difficult to debug!

Answer (score 2):

According to [OpenID Connect documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect?hl=en)

> For debugging purposes, you can use Google’s tokeninfo endpoint.
>   Suppose your ID token’s value is XYZ123. Then you would dereference
>   the URI
>   `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123`. If the
>   token is valid, the response would be its decoded JSON form.

As a result, you should use `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=` instead

Here is the sample result:

```
{
    "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "at_hash": "q5xc...",
    "aud": "6043....apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "sub": "10983809...",
    "email_verified": "true",
    "azp": "6043....apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "email": "...@gmail.com",
    "iat": "1453101827",
    "exp": "1453105427",
    "name": "BNK",
    "picture": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-XP8Sq0RiUvg/AAAAAAAAAAI/.../photo123.jpg",
    "given_name": "...",
    "family_name": "...",
    "locale": "en",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "411f5ba60aa6....ec50f90e8"
}
```